# Why I can't add Apps into LionServer's ProfileManager

Tags: iphone, ios, osx-lion, mdm

Today I install Lion Server.app in my OS(Mac OS X 10.7.3(Lion)) and configure the server. After  that I enroll my devices into the ProfileManager.

Try to push the Profile to my devices and control it is ok.

I want to add the App to my devices.(Distribution for Enterprise),but it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 1):

http://enterpriseios.com/mdm/Apple_Profile_Manager

You can't use Profile Manager for Enterprise Application delivery - you need to use either a 3rd Party MEAP solution like Apperian or you could sign up to Apple's Enterprise Application Developer Program and host the apps off an internal webserver and delivery URLs via Webclips from Profile Manager.

Answer (score 0):

that is not my experience at all, I am running Mountain Lion 10.8.2 and I am able to add my ipa files into profile manager.  to generate my ipa from xcode I simply make sure that I have the proper certificate for my distribution cert, and I check my release scheme is selected, next I choose archive and I check the option box that says enterprise distribution.  if you select enterprise distribution, you need to provide the details for your plist file (location, app title and png file) more info on Apple's website...

http://images.apple.com/iphone/business/docs/iOS_Apple_Configurator_Mar12.pdf